# I need to assign a variable via the following user message, how can I do this?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I'm writing a bot on discord py. I need to assign a variable via the following user message, how can I do this?

```
                    frole = # here I need to set a variable via the following message .family role MaosFamily
                    post = {
                        "_id": self.familydb.count_documents({}) + 1,
                        "role": frole,
                        "voice": None,
                        "boss": ctx.author.id,
                        "zam": None
                    }
                    self.shopdb.insert_one(post)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for).

Example:

```py
frole = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author==ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel)
```

Comment: access the message's content with `frole.content`